# Deleting fields from an attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, delete, error-000840

I have a layer that was constructed by multiple dissolve, merge, join's etc. by a previous person. So unsurprisingly the table is a complete mess. I only need 2 or 3 out of the 20 something fields that are in the table. However I can't seem to delete them, as the Delete button is grayed out. I found online that there is a workaround using the Delete Fields tool. But that produces:

> **ERROR 000840**
>   The value is not a Raster Layer. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Catalog Layer. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer.

Which gives dozens of hits here on GIS.stackexchange.com but they vary wildly by topic, but mostly about [arcpy](/questions/tagged/arcpy) or the modelbuilder.

The layer is saved in a layer package, if that might make a difference?

Comment: This doesn't pertain to the error message, but the Delete Field option is grayed out as long as you are in an edit session, if that is of any help.

Comment: @humperderp I'm aware, and am not in an edit session. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: What extension is your vector layer? the error you get seems to be saying you are using a tool for raster layer, when what you want to do is edit a vector layer. Try to export the layer into a shape file if it isn't already and try editing it again.

Comment: How and where to have you unpacked the layer package? If I drag and drop a layer package into ArcMap it unpacks into my documents and I can delete a field.

Comment: I'd try exporting the layer into a shapefile/feature class and try to delete the field from the new exported shapefiles.

Comment: @Hornbydd I just double clicked my layer package, and it opened up.

Comment: Delete is also grayed out if a field is required. Copying tables to a new workspace will usually get rid of the "required" condition. But starting from a mess, why not turn off the fields you don't want and export the data to a new feature?